# AutoComplete search on even one character android

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am using `AutoComplete` widget. It works fine for two characters search but doesen't work for one character. I want to auto complete work even when user enters only one character.

For example when I enter "1" it should show all list start  with "1".
Now its showing suggestions list for 2 characters for example "12".

Code:

```
zip.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                String from = "zip";
                new GetAutoComplete(url, from).execute();// getting list

            }
        }
    });



ArrayAdapter<Integer> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                MyActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_of_zip,
                zip_codes);
            zip.setAdapter(aa); // zip = autocomplete widget and zip_codes = arrayList
```

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean by count 0 there is no such thing.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Set your completionThreshold to 1.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/your_id" 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:completionThreshold="1" />
```

Or to do it dynamically use `mAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1)`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 12):

Makes the threshold as one so it starts from the first letter onwards. 
You can do that using:

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```